# Creating array of elements c# console

Tags: c#, console-application

i just try to make this.

writing a program which create an array of of integer numbers and initializes each the elements with the element's index value, multiplid by five.

print the result

and my code is :..

```
        Console.Title = " Arrays ";
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine(" This Program Is About Partial Automation Array   :-");
        Console.WriteLine(" ====================================================");

        Console.Write("\n Please Enter The Size Of Array :  ");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr1 = new int[n];
        Console.WriteLine(" =====================================");
        // Multible Process :-
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            arr1[i] = arr1[i] * 5;
        }
        // Displaying Process :-
        Console.WriteLine(" \nThe Result Is :-");
        Console.WriteLine(" ================");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" "+ arr1[i] + "\t");
        }
```

Comment: well, you seem to achieve it, what is your question.

Comment: Prob you should have: `arr1[i] = i * 5;`

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: Yes Kirill is right, I didn't notice that ;)

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk, thanks it work, 

can you please post it, to mark it as answered, and i glade for your help,.

Comment: @Just.Body, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change `arr1[i] = arr1[i] * 5;` to `arr1[i] = i * 5;`

Answer (score 0):

use linq:

```
  const int N = 10;
  var array = Enumerable.Range(0, N)
    .Select((x, i) => i * 5)
    .ToArray();

  foreach (var element in array) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Value: {element}");
  }
```